# travel salesman problem with capacity constraint

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, traversal

I'm trying to solve a simple TSP problem using CPLEX with an additional constraint.
At the beginning, my .mod look like this::

```
 // Stops
int n = 4;

// Indexes for the stops
range nodes = 1 .. n;

// Cost Matrix cij
int Cost[nodes][nodes] = ...;

// Decision variables xij
dvar boolean x[nodes][nodes];

// Rank variable ui
dvar float+ u[nodes];

// Objective function
minimize sum (i, j in nodes) x[i][j] * Cost[i][j];

// Constraints
subject to {

    forall (i in nodes) x[i][i] == 0; // Easier than adding i != j everywhere

    rule_one_out:
    forall (i in nodes) sum (j in nodes) x[i][j] == 1;

    rule_one_in:
    forall (j in nodes) sum (i in nodes) x[i][j] == 1;

    rule_no_subtour:
    forall (i, j in nodes : j != 1) u[i] + x[i][j] <= u[j] + (n - 1) * (1 - x[i][j]);

    u[1] == 0; // Fixes the rank of the first node
}
```

(The last constraint is to avoid subroute)

with .dat

```
Cost = [
[900,   350,    200,    750]
[350,   150,    400,    700]
[200,   400,    50, 290]
[235,   700,    290,    100]
];
```

It runs well and return

```
X =
[[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 0]
[1 0 0 0]];
```

As a result, being a,b,c and d the nodes, the optimal travel is:

```
a->c->b->d->a
```

But i'm trying to add a new constraint. A capacity constraint, imagining that the sales man is acctualy a bus and the problem is trying to find the short/fatest travel but it can't over populate the bus.
To do that, i used a new vector with the balance of people entryng and leaving the bus in each node/stop (a,b,c and d).

with a capacity of 100 people

```
Bal = [100 20 5 -100]
```

So in this case, what i expect, is that the first stop would be forced to be the node "d", as it is the only one who will reduce the number of people on the bus, as it started with 100.

what i tried so far was:

```
    // Stops
int n = 4;

// Indexes for the stops
range nodes = 1 .. n;

// Cost Matrix cij
int Cost[nodes][nodes] = ...;

// Balance Vector
int Bal[nodes]= ...;

// Decision variables xij
dvar boolean x[nodes][nodes];

// Rank variable ui
dvar float+ u[nodes];

// Objective function
minimize sum (i, j in nodes) x[i][j] * Cost[i][j];

// Constraints
subject to {

    forall (i in nodes) x[i][i] == 0; // Easier than adding i != j everywhere

    rule_one_out:
    forall (i in nodes) sum (j in nodes) x[i][j] == 1;

    rule_one_in:
    forall (j in nodes) sum (i in nodes) x[i][j] == 1;
    
    total_cap:
    forall (k in nodes) sum(i in 1 .. k) sum(j in nodes) x[i][j]*Bal[i] <= 100;

    rule_no_subtour:
    forall (i, j in nodes : j != 1) u[i] + x[i][j] <= u[j] + (n - 1) * (1 - x[i][j])
    u[1] == 0; // Fixes the rank of the first node }
```

but it would only work if the X matrix keep the route order line by line.

So i'm struggling to find a workround or a new constraint.

Comment: Look up some work on TSPTW aka tsp with time-windows as there is not not much difference between aggregating travel-time (and rejecting visits due to missed windows) or aggregating capacities / loads. If you would be okay to not use cplex, i would recommend or-tools routing-solver which is often more interesing in practice (but it's a heuristic -> no proofs). or-tools internal modelling-framework will also present an abstraction-concept named *dimensions* which they use for time-windows as well as (load) capacities further supporting my first recommendation.